# Is there a way to have an infinite surface size along the width or the height in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, infinite, surface

this is a short question I was just wondering in I could have a `pygame.surface()` with an infinite width.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have an infinite width/height. If you want to have an infinite looking image you would probably have to do something like using multiple Surfaces.

Comment: This seems to be a [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple answer

It is not possible to have infinitely big surfaces with pygame.

#### Complex Answer

It is not possible, because surfaces in pygame are storing data for every pixel in them.
In reality you can't have infinitely big objects, they are only theoretically infinite, but there is an alternative that would work.
Don't make infinitely big surface, make it expandable.

#### Example Implementations

This is the simplest one that came to my mind.

```py
def resize_surface(surf, size):
    ret = pygame.Surface(size)
    ret.blit(surf)
    return ret
```

But it is a bad solution - it will generate extra unnecessary pixels and you can't have negative positions.

What you can do is split whole space into chunks, where every chunk is something containing surface and coordinate. Surfaces have to be same size.

Example code:

```py
import pygame


class Space:
    chunck_size = (30, 30)
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.map = {}
    
    def set_at(self, x, y, color):
        cx, cy, rx, ry = self.get_real_pos(x, y)
        
        if (cx, cy) not in self.map:
            self.map[cx, cy] = self._generate_surface()
        
        self.map[cx, cy].set_at((rx, ry), color)
    
    def get_at(self, x, y):
        cx, cy, rx, ry = self.get_real_pos(x, y)
        
        if (cx, cy) not in self.map:
            self.map[cx, cy] = self._generate_surface()
        
        return self.map[cx, cy].get_at((rx, ry))
        
    def get_real_pos(self, x, y):
        chunck_x = (x - x % self.chunck_size[0]) // self.chunck_size[0]
        relative_x = x - chunck_x * self.chunck_size[0]
        
        chunck_y = (y - y % self.chunck_size[1]) // self.chunck_size[1]
        relative_y = y - chunck_y * self.chunck_size[1]
        
        return chunck_x, chunck_y, relative_x, relative_y
    
    def _generate_surface(self):
        return pygame.Surface(self.chunck_size)
```

#### Results:

```
>>> s = Space()
>>> s.set_at(100, 100, (255, 100, 0))
>>> s.get_at(100, 100)
(255, 100, 0, 255)
>>> s.set_at(-100, 0, (100, 0, 0))
>>> s.get_at(-100, 0)
(100, 0, 0, 255)
>>> s.get_at(-1000, -1000)
(0, 0, 0, 255)
```

Comment: Side note: It will **not** work with pygame.draw nor with pygame.draw_py (but with the last one you can change the code  to work properly).